# Why is the set of all Real Upper Triangular Square matrices not a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

My textbook indicates that the set of all upper triangular n ✕ n matrices is a real vector space, but the set of all upper triangular square matrices is not a real vector space.

Why is there a difference between the two? Shouldn't the upper triangular square matrix set also be a vector space?

Comment: I did. I used the exact same phrasing of the question from the online course I'm taking. I attached pictures to demonstrate my point.

Comment: did the pictures provide any clarity or still a typo?

Comment: Perfect! thank you for clarification

Comment: Pjonin gave a good explanation, of course for the second one if we are dealing with square matrices of different size then "the set of all upper triangular square matrices is not a real vector space" is true of course!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess what they mean is that you need to precise that they must be the same size and that you can’t have a vectorial space of matrices of size p and of size n.

But that’s quite unclear.

Comment: Yes of course! I did'n consider that but that must be the reason.